# duplicate 127.0.0.1 port, specifically for mongo

Tags: iptables, port, mongodb

I would like to duplicate port 127.0.0.1:27017 to 127.0.0.1:27018.

My initial attempts were using ip tables:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 27018 -j REDIRECT --to-port 27017
```

(And variations of this idea). But this did not work.

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27018
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.10
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27018/test
2019-01-12T04:04:12.403+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27018, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2019-01-12T04:04:12.404+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27018 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:148
exception: connect failed
```

What is the correct way of allowing one mongo instance to be accessible via 27017 and 27018.

Comment: What is your use case for binding `mongod` to multiple ports on the same network interface?

Answer (score 0):

Packets destined for the loopback interface do not pass through the `PREROUTING` chain. You need to use the `OUTPUT` chain.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp --dport 27018 -j REDIRECT --to-port 27017
```